# Exclude particular class name in CSS selector using html dom

Tags: html, class, parsing, dom

I want to import only texts that contain only class="item-name"
Not and class="item-name active"
How do you think I could apply the import?

The HTML code is :

```
<li class="list-item" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a class="item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="/">
        <span class="item-name" itemprop="name">Category</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="list-item" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a class="item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="/outlet">
        <span class="item-name" itemprop="name">Category 1</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="list-item" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a class="item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="/outlet/fragrance">
        <span class="item-name" itemprop="name">Category 2</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="list-item" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <span class="active-item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item">
        <span class="item-name active" itemprop="name">Title</span>
    </span>
</li>
```

My php code :

```
if ($html !== false) {
    $prod['id']=$html->find('span.code',0)->plaintext;
    $j=0;
    while (isset($html->find('span.item-name',$j)->plaintext)) {
        $cats[]=str_replace(['.',';'],' ',html_entity_decode($html->find('span.item-name',$j)->plaintext));
        $j++;
    }
    $prod['category']=implode(', ',$cats);
    unset($cats);
}
```

UPDATE I fix

```
          if ($html !== false) {
              $prod['id']=$html->find('span.code',0)->plaintext;
              $j=0;
              while (isset($html->find('a.item',$j)->plaintext)) {
                 $cats[]=str_replace([' ','&#39',';'],' ',html_entity_decode($html->find('a.item',$j)->plaintext));
                 $new = preg_replace(['(\s+)u', '(^\s|\s$)u'], [' ', ''], $cats);
                 $j++;
              }
              $prod['category']=implode(', ',$new);
              unset($new);
              }
```

Comment: Could you use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector?

Comment: to expand on @showdev's comment, `find('span.item-name:not(.active)',$j)`